# how to costum modify each row of a column in a huge dataset?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a big dataset, consisting of around 190,000 rows and 6 clumns, this is a brief view of it:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrbfc.png)

the problem is that the second column should only be integers not string or decimals, I should change it to an integer of my own choice but I have to keep up with the iterations of the same name, so e.g.

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000001.1 -> 11

APLT01000003.1 -> 12

APLT01000003.1 -> 12

but this is huge file and I cannot know all thousands of different names to replace them, 
can it be done with python? and if yes, how?

Comment: not sure i fully understood, what is your logic of changing it to integers? do you want each unique value to have it's own ID (i.e. APLT01000001.1 to become 11 and APLT01000003.1 to become 12) and so on? do they start from 11 and go upwards?

Comment: the software doesn't accept anything but integer in this column. the value attribution doesn't really matter I just chose to start from 11 onward and yes your guess about value attribution is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously i don't know the logic of your new values assignment, so i assumed that each unique value will have it's own new value (integer) starting from 11, if that's the case, the below should do the trick, if not, then you can use it as a guideline and tweak it around your logic:

```
import pandas as pd

#get unique values from your second column
uniqueVals = pd.DataFrame(data=df['2ndColumn'].unique().tolist())
#give appropraite name (IDs)
uniqueVals = uniqueVals.rename(columns={uniqueVals.columns[0]: 'IDs'})
#create your new values (assuming it's starting from 11)
uniqueVals['newID'] = uniqueVals.index + 11

#merge your dataframe to the new values lookup
df = df.merge(uniqueVals, how='left', left_on=['2ndColumn'], right_on=['IDs'])
#get your second column the new value
df['2ndColumn'] = df['newID']
#drop additional columns added during the merge
df = df.drop(['IDs', 'newID'], axis=1)
```

Comment: I am very much beginner! I did this `df = pd.read_csv("./Melitaea.snp")` then `uniqueVals = pd.DataFrame(data=df['col2'].unique().tolist())`, it says col2 is not defined, I even tried `df[:,1]` to select the second column but didn't work

Comment: is your second column in that df named 'col2'?

Comment: If your .snp file is not comma delimited but space delimited instead, use  `delimiter=' '` when reading it in.

Comment: it was tab delimited and now is working correctly, thanks